# Using inlineCallbacks

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I'm new to Twisted and I'm trying to write a simple resource which
displays a list of names from a database, here's a part of my code:

```
#code from my ContactResource class
def render_GET(self, request):
    def print_contacts(contacts, request):
        for c in contacts:
            request.write(c.name)
        if not request.finished:
            request.finish()
    d = Contact.find() #Contact is a Twistar DBObject subclass
    d.addCallback(print_contacts, request)
    return NOT_DONE_YET
```

My question is: how can I change this method to use the inlineCallbacks decorator?

Answer (score 11):

A `render_GET` method may not return a `Deferred`.  It may only return a string or `NOT_DONE_YET`.  Any method decorated with `inlineCallbacks` will return a `Deferred`.  So, you may not decorate `render_GET` with `inlineCallbacks`.

Of course, nothing stops you from calling any other function you want in `render_GET`, including one that returns a `Deferred`.  Just throw the `Deferred` away instead of returning it from `render_GET` (of course, make sure that the `Deferred` never fires with a failure, or by throwing it away you may be missing some error reporting...).

So, for example:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def _renderContacts(self, request):
    contacts = yield Contact.find() 
    for c in contacts:
        request.write(c.name)
    if not request.finished:
        request.finish()


def render_GET(self, request):
    self._renderContacts(request)
    return NOT_DONE_YET
```

I recommend at least taking a look at [txyoga](https://readthedocs.org/projects/txyoga/) and [klein](http://dreid.org/programming/2012/03/28/klein-a-twisted.web-microframework/) if you're going to be doing any serious web development with Twisted.  Even if you don't want to use them, they should give you some good ideas about how you can structure your code and accomplish various common tasks like this one.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: I didn't find an example how to combine twisted.web with inlineCallbacks, but here are two suggestions. The first is preferable, but I'm not sure if it works.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def render_GET(self, request):
    contacts = yield Contact.find() 
    defer.returnValue(''.join(c.name for c in contacts)


@inlineCallbacks
def render_GET(self, request):
    contacts = yield Contact.find() 
    for c in contacts:
        request.write(c.name)
    if not request.finished:
        request.finish()
    defer.returnValue(NOT_DONE_YET)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @schlamar, but it doesn't work. This throws "Request did not return a string" error.