# Twisted: Advise on using txredisapi library required

Tags: python, redis, twisted

Below I provided a code example which simply respond to HTTP GET request with the data from Redis:

*Request:* `http://example.com:8888/?auth=zefDWDd5mS7mcbfoDbDDf4eVAKb1nlDmzLwcmhDOeUc`
*Response:* `get: u'"True"'`

The purpose of this code is to serve as a REST server (that's why I'm using lazyConnectionPool) responding to the requests, and using data from Redis (read/ write).

What I need to do:

1. Run multiple requests to Redis inside render_GET of the IndexHandler (like GET, HMGET, SET, etc)
2. Run multiple requests in a transaction inside render_GET of the IndexHandler

I've tried multiple ways to do that (including examples from the txredisapi library), but due to lack of experience failed to do that. Could you please advise on questions 1) and 2).

Thanks in advance.

```
import txredisapi as redis

from twisted.application import internet
from twisted.application import service
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.web.resource import Resource


class Root(Resource):
    isLeaf = False


class BaseHandler(object):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        Resource.__init__(self)


class IndexHandler(BaseHandler, Resource):
    def _success(self, value, request, message):
        request.write(message % repr(value))
        request.finish()

    def _failure(self, error, request, message):
        request.write(message % str(error))
        request.finish()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        try:
            auth = request.args["auth"][0]
        except:
            request.setResponseCode(404, "not found")
            return ""

        d = self.db.hget(auth, 'user_add')
        d.addCallback(self._success, request, "get: %s\n")
        d.addErrback(self._failure, request, "get failed: %s\n")
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET


# Redis connection parameters
REDIS_HOST = '10.10.0.110'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 1
REDIS_POOL_SIZE = 1
REDIS_RECONNECT = True

# redis connection
_db = redis.lazyConnectionPool(REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_DB, REDIS_POOL_SIZE)

# http resources
root = Root()
root.putChild("", IndexHandler(_db))

application = service.Application("web")
srv = internet.TCPServer(8888, server.Site(root), interface="127.0.0.1")
srv.setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: This code looks good. I have not run it, but what is the problem with it?

Comment: The provided code is absolutely functional, and don't have any issues with current implementation. What I need is to extend it with: (i) Run multiple requests to Redis inside render_GET of the IndexHandler (like GET, HMGET, SET, etc); (ii) Run multiple requests in a transaction inside render_GET of the IndexHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding first question:

There is a few ways to generalize to making multiple database requests in a single HTTP request.

For example you can make multiple requests:

```
d1 = self.db.hget(auth, 'user_add')
d2 = self.db.get('foo')
```

Then you can get a callback to trigger when all of these **simultaneous** requests are finished (see `twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList`).

Or you can use `inlineCallbacks` if you need **sequential** requests.  For example:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def do_redis(self):
    foo = yield self.db.get('somekey')
    bar = yield self.db.hget(foo, 'bar') # Get 'bar' field of hash foo
```

But you will need to read more about combining `inlineCallbacks` with `twisted.web` (there are [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712752/using-inlinecallbacks/14734728) on that topic you should look up).

Regarding question 2:

Transactions are really ugly to do without using `inlineCallbacks`.  There is an example at [txredisapi homepage](https://github.com/fiorix/txredisapi) that shows it using `inlineCallbacks`.

Comment: Thanks @Max, it looks like I've came to the same solution as you described using `inlineCallbacks`. I think it works for me, and I'll definitely try solution with `DeferredList`.

Comment: You are welcome, @PavelKlymenko.  IMHO, `DeferredList` is OK in small quantities but `inlineCallbacks` are worth the code simplicity in the long run.

Comment: I think you're right @Max. Implemented via `inlineCallbacks`. Thanks again.

Comment: Author of txredisapi here. I'd say `inlineCallbacks` is definitely the way to go.