# What is the purpose of @inlineCallbacks in the python autobahn code based on twisted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, autobahn

I see the code `@inlineCallbacks` in the autobahn examples all the time. An example is below;

```
class Component(ApplicationSession):
   """
   An application component that publishes an event every second.
   """

   @inlineCallbacks
   def onJoin(self, details):
      print("session attached")
      counter = 0
      while True:
         print(".")
         self.publish('com.myapp.topic1', counter)
         counter += 1
         yield sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationRunner
   runner = ApplicationRunner("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws", "realm1")
   runner.run(Component)
```

What is the purpose of @inlineCallbacks?

Comment: This is twisted decorator. Question is  possibly duplicate of [Using inlineCallbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712752/using-inlinecallbacks)